# Access violation while copying data dynamically to a 2D character array

Tags: c, windows, recursion

Kindly refer to my recursive code that parses a directory having large count of files. Code copies all file paths in a character array. Am I missing something that I am getting an access violation in the recursive call? Thanks in advance

```
// global variables
int iFileCount = 0;
char *szFilePath[MAX_PATH];

// Recursive function to get all files in the path specified
void FindFilesRec(const char *szDir)
{
    int i, iRet;
    HANDLE hFind;
    char sPath[MAX_PATH]; 
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    LARGE_INTEGER filesize;

    sprintf(sPath, "%s\\*.*", szDir);

    hFind = FindFirstFile(sPath, &ffd);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) 
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("FindFirstFile error"));
        return;
    }

    i = 0;
    for (i;;i++)
    {
        if ((strcmp(ffd.cFileName, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(ffd.cFileName, "..") != 0))
        {
            sprintf(sPath, "%s\\%s", szDir, ffd.cFileName); 
            if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                _tprintf(TEXT("\n  %s   <DIR>\n"), ffd.cFileName);
                {
                    FindFilesRec(sPath);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                filesize.LowPart = ffd.nFileSizeLow;
                filesize.HighPart = ffd.nFileSizeHigh;
                _tprintf(TEXT("\n  %s   %ld bytes\n"), ffd.cFileName, filesize.QuadPart);
                szFilePath[iFileCount] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(sPath) + 1);
                szFilePath[iFileCount][strlen(sPath)] = '\0';
                memcpy(szFilePath[iFileCount], sPath, strlen(sPath));
                iFileCount++;
            }
        }

        iRet = FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd);
        if (0 == iRet)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    FindClose(hFind);

    return;
}
```

Comment: And what did the debugger tell you? Where did it crash? How do you call the function? What are `iFileCount` AAND `szFilePath`? How and where are they initialized? Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Crash was in the recursive call: FindFilesRec(sPath);
iFileCount would be the total number of files. szFilePath is a charater array storing all FilePaths

Comment: Just this error message: "Unhandled exception at 0x01603e00 in FirstScanner.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation."
If I break, control stops at FindFilesRec(sPath);

Comment: Where is the declaration of `szFilePath`? You might consider making this a complete example so we could see exactly what you're seeing. It would only take a few more lines of code.

Comment: szFilePath is global as:
char *szFilePath[MAX_PATH];

Comment: The recursive functin itself seems to work fine if I remove the parts where `szFilePath` and `iFileCount` are involved. So We cannot help unless you provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Are there more than 260 files? You don't check for going past the end of `szFilePath` so my crystal ball says you're overwriting memory. Adding it as a local doesn't work, it's a recursive function.  Just make a complete example.

Comment: Sure. Program is supposed to work on large count of files. If that's the case, what might be the changes?

Comment: "*szFilePath is global*" you last edit made it local.

Comment: @alk: For the purpose of understanding

Comment: @Sarju your last edit completely modifies the behaviour of your program, it __must__ stay global.

Comment: @Sarju I edit your question so it makes senses again

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Done

Comment: C'mon guys. Not that bad a question for a downvote. ;)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is totally unrelated to the recursive function which seems to work fine (I didn't check in details though).

`char *szFilePath[MAX_PATH];` declares an array of `MAX_PATH` pointers to `char*`. So as soon as `iFileCount` exceeds the value `MAX_PATH`, you are starting to overwrite memory and this results in undefined behaviour.

You are basically doing this:

```
char *szFilePath[MAX_PATH];
int iFileCount;

void foo()
{
  char sPath[] = "bar";
  szFilePath[iFileCount] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(sPath) + 1);
  szFilePath[iFileCount][strlen(sPath)] = '\0';
  memcpy(szFilePath[iFileCount], sPath, strlen(sPath));
  iFileCount++;
}

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    foo();   // problem if i exceeds MAX_PATH
}
```

Which will also fail just as your program.

You need to handle `szFilePath` this differently.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Problem here is, I do not have the count of files in advance and I need to add the file path in szFilePath dynamically. Also I cannot first run the program to just get the count of files. It would be time consuming. Any pointers how I could do that?

Comment: Very roughly like this: Using `malloc` and `realloc`. Allocate for example space for 100 pointers with `szFilePath = malloc(100*sizeof(char*))`, and once `iFileCount` is `>= 100` allocate more space with `szFilePath = realloc((iFileCount + 100)*sizeof(char*));` etc. This is a good exercise. Declare `szFilePath` like this `char *szFilePath;`, and best rename it to something else, the `sz` prefix is misleading.

Comment: Thanks. Would try that :)

Comment: "*Declare like this `char *szFilePath;`*" are you sure? I'd give it another `*`.

Comment: @alk no it's a typo. It should of course be `char **szFilePath;`.

Comment: @Sarju not `char *szFilePath` but `char **szFilePath;`. A typo.